# vedio js gear icon not visible for quality selection

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video.js

i'm trying to show the gear of quality selection
i use videojs and [videojs-quality-selector](https://github.com/silvermine/videojs-quality-selector)
the video is runnable but no gear to choose the quality
help me with this guys , thank you.

html code:

```
<head>
<link href="plugins/css/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@silvermine/videojs-quality-selector/dist/css/quality-selector.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

 <video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/js/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@silvermine/videojs-quality-selector/dist/js/silvermine-videojs-quality-selector.min.js"></script>
```

js code:

```
var options, player;

options = {
    controlBar: {
        children: [
            'playToggle',
            'progressControl',
            'volumePanel',
            'qualitySelector',
            'fullscreenToggle',
        ],
    },
};

player = videojs('video_1', options);

player.src([{
        src: 'video1.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '720P',
    },
    {
        src: 'video2.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '480P',
        selected: true,
    },
    {
        src: 'video3.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '360P',
    },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because you are trying to initialise the player twice:

- Once with the `data-setup='{}'` attribute, with no options
- Once with `videojs('video_1', options)`, with setup options including the plugin.

If the plugin has already been initialised (with `data-setup`), calling `videojs('video_1', options)` will just return the existing player, not re-initialise it with the requested options.

Easiest solution is just to remove `data-setup='{}'`.